# System.ObjectDisposedException with Virtual property in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi can anybody help with this I am getting the above error when trying to display data about the Carmodels in my view

```
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CarId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Registration { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual CarModels Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string RegistrationYear { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ChassisNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
```

And here is the function

```
public static List<Cars> GetRegistrationCars(int registration)
        {
            List<Cars> registrationCars = new List<Cars>();
            using (var db = new EventsContext())
            {
                registrationCars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.RegistrationId == registration).ToList();
            }

            return registrationCars.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah ha figured it out in the end Thanks for the suggestions

```
 public static List<Cars> GetRegistrationCars(int registration)
        {
            List<Cars> registrationCars = new List<Cars>();

            using (var db = new FerrariEventsContext())
            {
                registrationCars = db.Cars.Include(m=> m.Model).Where(c => c.RegistrationId == registration).ToList();
            }

            return registrationCars;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's attempting to lazy load the `Model` property after the list is returned (and the `DbContext` is disposed).  Either eager load the `Model` property or disable lazy loading/proxy generation.

Comment: To disable lazy loading: yourContextName.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing of the context before you call `ToList()` on it. Move `ToList()` to inside the `using` block

```
    public static List<Cars> GetRegistrationCars(int registration)
    {
        List<Cars> registrationCars = new List<Cars>();
        using (var db = new EventsContext())
        {
            registrationCars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.RegistrationId == registration).ToList();
            return registrationCars.ToList();
        }
        // Here is too late - using has Disposed() the EventsContext() already so ToList will throw an exception
     }
```

Edit:

This is assuming that the `ToList` call on the linq query isn't actually there (I didn't spot that first time round), but now I'm hoping it's a typo :)

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice that before... usually calling `ToList()` on a list is kind of pointless - foiled by the scrollbar haha :)

Comment: Yeah sorry shouldnt have included that, that was me clutching at straws adding it again

Comment: Is it a typo then? The ToList call on the Linq query or is it actually there? Without it you would get the error you mentioned... with it I'm not so sure!

Comment: Actually looking at it since you declared `registrationCars` as a list it looks like you'd have to call ToList anyway or the `IEnumerable` result wouldn't fit the type - must be something else then - where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: What line does the throw come from?

Comment: I get the Error in the View When I call @item.Model.ModelName

Comment: Ok so it's MVC and you are trying to lazy load then?

Answer (score -1):

One more advice: `GetRegistrationCars()` should be asynchronous - by changing `ToList()` to awaiting `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Only if the method has been declared `async` as well, and only if the application is generally using an `async/await` model.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.